# Arguments of __new__ and __init__ for metaclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

I am a bit surprised by the method call order and the different arguments when overriding `new` and `init` in a metaclass. Consider the following:

```
class AT(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct):
        print(f"Name as received in new: {name}")
        return super().__new__(mcs, name + 'HELLO', bases + (list,), dct)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        print(f"Name as received in init: {name}")
        pass

class A(metaclass=AT):
    pass

A.__name__
```

The output is:

```
Name as received in new: A
Name as received in init: A
'AHELLO'
```

In short I would have expected `init` to receive `AHELLO` with the argument `name`.

I imagined that `__init__` was called by `super().__new__`: if the call is not done in the overridden `__new__` then my `__init__` is not called.

Could someone clarify how `__init__` is called in this case?

For information my use case for this is that I wanted to make creation of classes, in a special case, easier at runtime by providing only a single "base" class (and not a tuple), I then added this code in `__new__`:

```
if not isinstance(bases, tuple):
            bases = (bases, )
```

however, I found out that I also need to add it in `__init__`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `__init__` method is obviously called and the reason for that is because your `__new__` method is returning an instance of your class.

From [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**new**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> If `__new__()` returns an instance of cls, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will be invoked like `__init__(self[, ...])`, where self is the new instance and the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to `__new__()`.

As you can see the arguments passed to `__init__` are those passed to `__new__` method's caller not when you call it using `super`. It's a little bit vague but that's what it means if you read it closely.

And regarding the rest it works just as expected:

```
In [10]: A.__bases__
Out[10]: (list,)

In [11]: a = A()

In [12]: a.__class__.__bases__
Out[12]: (list,)
```

Comment: Thanks, very clear, I missed the part " the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to __new__()" when reading the reference.

Comment: If I may: you could clarify the answer: make it clear that the quoted part refers to "self" and "instance" which in this specific case 'translates' to 'mcs' and 'class'. Also, I'm not sure that your example in the end in complete, did you forget to copy/paste some part ?

Comment: @CedricH. I think it suffice that you mention it here. The last example is written based on your code and i think it's clear.

Answer (score 6):

The fact is that what orchestrates the call of `__new__` and `__init__` of an ordinary class is the `__call__` method on its metaclass. The code in the `__call__` method of `type`, the default metatype, is in C, but the equivalent of it in Python would be:

```
class type:
    ...
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
         instance = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)  # __new__ is actually a static method - cls has to be passed explicitly
         if isinstance(instance, cls):
               instance.__init__(*args, **kw)
         return instance
```

That takes place for most object instantiation in Python, including when instantiating classes themselves - the metaclass is implicitly called as part of a class statement. In this case, the `__new__` and `__init__` called from `type.__call__` are the methods on the **metaclass** itself. And in this case, `type` is acting as the "metametaclass" - a concept seldom needed, but it is what creates the behavior you are exploring.

When creating classes, `type.__new__` will be responsible for calling the class (not the metaclass) `__init_subclass__`, and its descriptors' `__set_name__` methods - so, the "metametaclass" `__call__` method can't control that.

So, if you want the args passed to the metaclass `__init__` to be programmatically modified, the "normal" way will be to have a "metametaclass", inheriting from `type` and distinct from your metaclass itself, and override its `__call__` method:

```
class MM(type):
    def __call__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kw):
        name = modify(name)
        cls = metacls.__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kw)
        metacls.__init__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kw)
        return cls
        # or you could delegate to type.__call__, replacing the above with just
        # return super().__call__(modify(name), bases, namespace, **kw)
```

Of course that is a way to get to go closer to "turtles all way to the bottom"  than anyone would ever like in production code.

An alternative is to keep the modified name as an attribute on the metaclass, so that its `__init__` method can take the needed information from there, and ignore the name passed in from its own metaclass' `__call__` invocation. The information channel can be an ordinary attribute on the metaclass instance. Well - it happens that the "metaclass instance" is the class being created itself - and oh, see - that the name passed to `type.__new__` already gets recorded in it - on the `__name__` atribute.

In other words, all you have to do to use a class name modified in a metaclass `__new__` method in its own `__init__` method, is to ignore the passed in `name` argument, and use `cls.__name__` instead:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kw):
        name = modified(name)
        return super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kw)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kw):
        name = cls.__name__  # noQA  (otherwise linting tools would warn on the overriden parameter name)
        ...
```

Comment: Crystal clear, thansk! My example about `name` was simplified, actually I needed to modify `bases`, however, your last point is a good trick.