# Metaclass of metaclass?

Tags: metaprogramming, metaclass

At my OOP theory exam I was asked a question "What is a metaclass? What is a metaclass of metaclass?". I answered first one easily, but have no idea about the second one. Is there even something like "metaclasses of metaclasses" in any programming language, or even theoritically? I tried implementing something like that in Python 3, but it seems it's a bit too complicated for my (I only had simple Python course for 1 semester).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

I will use the Python language to explain how can that be - maybe it is the language where metaclasses are more palpable (at least it is the language with the majority of questions involving metaclasses here).

So, in an OOP language where "classes" are first class objects - that is, they are themselves objects, and all the rules that apply to other objects apply to classes as well - they just happen to be the "template" for other kind of objects, these classes themselves are instances of "something". This something is the "metaclass" - which is just a word to designate the "class of a class".

And it happens that this "metaclass", the class of a class is an object as well, just as other classes. And as such, it also is an instance of a class - this class of the metaclass is what can be named the "metametaclass".

Now, bringing it down to a concrete example in Python - by default, the metaclass for classes in Python is `type`. That is, `type` is the class which instances are classes.

The language does have ingenious mechanisms that make it practical in some points to inherit a class from `type`, and then work with custom meta-classes. 
So, what is the class of `type`? That will be the "metametaclass"  for most (or all) classes in Python.

And as it goes, the class of "type" is "type" itself. yes - it is a circular reference, without which the object hierarchy of the language could not be bootstraped. I don't know if other languages do that differently - but in Python it is quite patent:

```
>>> class A:
...    pass
... 
>>> type(A)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(type(A))
<class 'type'>
>>> type(type(A)) is type(A)
True
```

Now, besides working like that as a concept, it actually can be used as  a metametaclass, and there are mechanisms of the language that can be tweaked by inheriting `type` for that purpose. (Normally it will be inherited to be customized as an "ordinary" metaclass).

By coincidence, I had an use case for the "metametaclass" exemplified this very week, in a question here - [by customizing Python's `type` `__call__` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56520882/108205), instead of `__new__` or `__init__`,  and using this custom class as the "metaclass for a metaclass" one can actually control how those methods are called and the parameters passed to them methods when an ordinary class is be created.