# Why does `type.__new__` call `__init_subclass__`?

Tags: python, metaclass

I noticed that I couldn't use `__init_subclass__` with Django model classes in quite the way I wanted to. It seems that the metaclass hasn't finished creating a child class by the time that a parent class' `__init_subclass__` method is run. While I understand what the issue is, and can circumvent it by making a custom metaclass, what I don't understand is **why**!

In my head, I tend to think that any calls like `__new__` should be done before any calls like `__init__` happen. But this isn't the case for metaclasses and `__init_subclass__`, as demonstrated here:

```py
class MetaMeta(type):
    print('parsing MetaMeta')
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('entering MetaMeta.__call__')
        instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        print('leaving MetaMeta.__call__')
        return instance

class Meta(type, metaclass=MetaMeta):
    print('parsing Meta')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('  entering Meta.__init__')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print('  leaving Meta.__init__')
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'  entering Meta.__new__')
        instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        print('  leaving Meta.__new__')
        return instance

class Parent(object, metaclass=Meta):
    print('parsing Parent')
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('    entering Parent.__init_subclass__')
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kwargs)
        print('    leaving Parent.__init_subclass__')

class Child(Parent):
    print('parsing Child')
```

Which results in:

```
parsing MetaMeta
parsing Meta
parsing Parent
entering MetaMeta.__call__
  entering Meta.__new__
  leaving Meta.__new__
  entering Meta.__init__
  leaving Meta.__init__
leaving MetaMeta.__call__
parsing Child
entering MetaMeta.__call__
  entering Meta.__new__
    entering Parent.__init_subclass__
    leaving Parent.__init_subclass__
  leaving Meta.__new__
  entering Meta.__init__
  leaving Meta.__init__
leaving MetaMeta.__call__
```

A metaclass can still be setting up the class in `Meta.__new__` after `__init_subclass__` is called. Which seems odd to me. Why is that the case, and is there any way to provide code in `Parent` (without a custom metaclass) that is run completely after `Meta.__new__` (and probably before `Meta.__init__`)?

Or am I missing something completely?

FYI, I found some related topics, but not quite what I was looking for:

- [The call order of python3 metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53246017/the-call-order-of-python3-metaclass)
- [Arguments of __new__ and __init__ for metaclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514586/arguments-of-new-and-init-for-metaclasses)
- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation

Perhaps a more concise way to ask this question is "why does Python (v3.9 at least) have `Meta.__new__` invoke `Parent.__init_subclass__`, instead of having `MetaMeta.__call__` invoke it immediately after `__new__` is complete?

Note that after asking, I did find some python.org discussion around this topic, but I don't think they clarify why:

- https://bugs.python.org/issue42775
- https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/thread/ZMRRNSFSLJZDGGZ66CFCYQBINU62CDNX/

Answer (score 2):

Tricky.

So, it is this way, because it is made so in the language. When adding features for the class creation processes, people did not allow for customization of when `__init_subclass__`, or the decriptors `__set_name__`, or the final linearization (mro) is calculated: that is all done at once inside `type.__new__` - and any metaclass written will have to call `type.__new__` at some point.

However, there is a possible workaround: if `type.__new__` won't "see" an `__init_subclass__` method, it won't be called.

Therefore, it is possible for a child metaclass to stash away `__init_subclass__`, call the parent `__new__`, and then, before leaving its own `__new__` to restore and call `__init_subclass__`.

So, if the problem is specifcially that you need `__init_subclass__` to run after Django's metaclass `__new__` is completly done, I can think of  two options, which both involve inheriting from Django's ORM metaclass, modifying it, and using that as the metaclass for your models.

Then the first option is simply to use another method name than `__init_subclass__` in your project. Your custom metaclass calls `super().__new__()` , Django and Python do their thing, and you call your `__init_subclass2__` (or whaterver name you pick).
I think this is the most maintainable and straightforward way to go.

The second option would be what I mentioned earlier: your `__new__` method checks all bases for any occurrence of `__init_subclass__`, delete then temporarily from the classes where they are, storing the original methods, call `super().__new__()`, then restore the `__init_subclass__` methods, and call them afterwards. This has the advantage of working with existing  `__init_subclass__` in the hyerarchy as they are (as long as the classes themselves are written in Python and not native code: in which case temporarily removing the method won't work). It has the severe disadvantage of ou having to scan the mro by yourself (ou will have to re-do the linearization) searching all existing `__init_subclass__` and restoring them afterwards - there might be some hard to spot corner cases.